# DiscordJS Database Not Storing Information Ideally

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to get the Discord bot to create a database that is basically the user map (a row for each user and columns for ID, nick name, avatar URL, etc) when it receives a !getdata command.

I've gotten to the point where the database successfully takes data, in this case the username and user ID, but it displays all the unique values in two columns as long comma separated values (i.e. the username column displays 'user1,user2,user3').

I'm sure this is by design, but I'm really struggling with restructuring. I'd like to either have it take all the data from an object map (client.users or message.guild.members) but I cannot figure it out.

The other option, which is what I'm trying now, is to create a row for each user and then fill in the values that I want to store, but I'm getting nowhere fast.

I'm very new with SQLite (and node/DiscordJS/JS for that matter), so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const sql = require('sqlite3');

let db = new sql.Database("users.sqlite", (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to the database', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Database connected.')
    }
})

let token = process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN;
let prefix = process.env.PREFIX ;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(username TEXT, id TEXT)`);
})

client.on('message', function(message) {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix));

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'getdata') {
        let username = message.guild.members.map(m=>m.user.username);
        let userid = message.guild.members.map(m=>m.user.id);
        db.run(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users(username, id) VALUES(?,?)`, [`${username}`,`${userid}`]);
        return message.channel.send(`User database updated.`);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

If you're curious as to the formatting or way things are written, the answer is two fold:

1. I'm pretty new at this
2. This was the only way I could get the values in the database to return something other than null

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, welcome to the site.

I hope that I can shine some light here without diving into refactoring your code or making you change anything major.

One thing sticks out to me as to *why* you are storing an array instead of a single value.

```
let username = message.guild.members.map(m=>m.user.username);
let userid = message.guild.members.map(m=>m.user.id);
```

The `.map` call returns an array, not a single value.

Each user that issues a command is part of the message object. If I remember correctly, you would want this to be something like...

*(simplified version)*

```
const { username, id } = message.member.user;
db.run(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users(username, id) VALUES(?,?)`, [username, id]);
// ...
```

[User documentation can be found here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

**Edit:**

If you wanted to build the database for all users in that one command you could do something like the following with a bulk insert... (quick and dirty)

```
db.serialize(() => {
  db.run('BEGIN TRANSACTION;');
  // execute inserts in transaction
  for (const m of message.guild.members) {
    db.run('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users(username, id) VALUES(?,?);', [m.user.username, m.user.id]);
  }
  // commit all inserts :)
  db.run('COMMIT;')
});

message.channel.send('User database updated.');
```

[Control flow documenation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow)

Hopefully this points you in the right direction :)

Comment: `message.member.user` can be shortened to `message.author`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely worked for pulling my own user data and giving it an independent row in the database, but what if I was trying to get the information for all users in the guild? This is what I was attempting by pulling the array -- which does pull all the information for all users, but it bunches it up under one column with values separated by commas. Is there a way to have the database build a row for each member of the guild?

Comment: @edgetechnician i've updated the answer with a bulk insert scenario for creating all users in one command :)

Comment: this is awesome! thank you. still getting compile errors, but I see where you're going with this. I'll play around and post what how it goes, but this definitely looks to be exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!